# Invariance of Diagonally Dominance Property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, similar-matrices

Does the property of diagonal dominance of a matrix remain invariant under some similarity transformation?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Any matrix with all distinct eigenvalues is similar to a diagonal matrix.

Comment: That's true, infact, any diagonlizable matrix has this invariant property...can we say in general?

Comment: Diagonal matrices are diagonally dominant, of course.  And it's easy to find diagonalizable matrices that are not diagonally dominant.

Comment: You are right, we cannot say a diagonalizable matrix is a diagonally dominant matrix. My mistake.

Comment: Your answer also not fits then..since (1,2;1/2,1) has two distinct eigenvalues 0 and 2, yet the matrix is  not a diagonally dominant.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer also not fits then..since (1,2;1/2,1) has two distinct eigenvalues 0 and 2, yet the matrix is  not a diagonally dominant.